# putting an nsnumber or nsstring in the  initWithLatitude:

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, cllocation

I'm stuck and stupid too, I'm trying to put an `NSString` or a `NSNumber` into the `initWithLatitude` of the `CLLocation`. If anyone could help it would be great.

Heres the code

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:53.778702 longitude:-0.271887];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:53.683267 longitude:-0.011330];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance in miles: %4.1f", [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]/1609.344]; 
[location1 release];
```

and I'm trying to replace `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:53.778702 longitude:-0.271887]` with `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon]`

Comment: Looks like your problem is solved, but FYI - if you're using ARC, you need to remove `[location1 release]`. The compiler handles that for you.

Answer (score 5):

`CLLocationDegrees` is a `double`, so you do

```
[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[someNSNumber doubleValue] longitude:[someNSString doubleValue]];
```

Comment: This worked great thanks, exactly what I needed! God status is still valid

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `CLLocationDegrees` data type to operate with your location values? This type is just a ordinary double data type

```
/*
 *  CLLocationDegrees
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    Type used to represent a latitude or longitude coordinate in degrees under the WGS 84 reference
 *    frame. The degree can be positive (North and East) or negative (South and West).  
 */
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

Comment: Found the example above and it works fine now, is what you saying a better way ? Didnt realise there was another way of doing it.

Comment: If you have your data as NSNumber then NO

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: (CLLocationDegrees) [lat doubleValue] longitude: (CLLocationDegrees) [lon doubleValue]];
```

This works whether `lat` and `lon` are NSStrings or NSNumbers.